# How to pass multiple double quotes in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, string

I should construct and pass following text in my JSON scheme. Here is how it should look:

```
r"""any-text-goes-here"""
```

Here is how I decided to construct it:

```
function make(text) {
    return `r"""${text}"""`;
}
```

The function above takes any string and converts it to desired format. But, when I return it in my API as one of fields of JSON, it looks like following:

```
"r\"\"\"any-text-goes-here\"\"\""
```

I want to avoid backslashes. I understand that those slashes is needed by Javascript to properly work, but can I remove them, because client side awaits how I described above. Is it possible technically? How can I solve problem?

Comment: You can do anything you want to the text once it has been returned.

Comment: No, you cant. they need to be escaped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON strings are delimited by `"` characters.

`"` characters can be included in a JSON string **only** by using an escape sequence.

Escape sequences start with a `\`.

You can't avoid the backslashes.

See the grammar from the [JSON website](https://www.json.org/json-en.html):

[image: grammar visualisation]

Comment: You mean the only possible solution is to remove that backslahes on client side?

Comment: Which running the JSON through a JSON parser will do.